Why PostgreSQL user have no permission to select?
I have installed postgresql 16.2 in debian10 by apt.
Then I use user postgres login, and create a database in psql-commindline.
Then I created a schema jiaofayuan in pgtest, and then created a user named pguser by postgres in psql.
    # create database pgtest;
    # create schema jiaofayuan;
    # create user pguser with password 'Adminadmin';
    # grant all privileges on database pgtest,pgtest2 to pguser;
    # grant all privileges on all tables in schema public,jiaofayuan to pguser;

The postgresql server IP is 192.168.208.221,and my PC IP is 192.168.208.12,the pgadmin4 is installed in 192.168.208.221.
I have configed the access permission in pg_hbd.conf.
There is a table named cities in public,a table named city in jiaofayuan,
Why pguser can exec
    # select * from public.cities;

but have no permission to exec:
    # select * from jiaofayuan.city;

is there sth I didnot config correctly?
Thank you !
The schema info:

The error msg:

The hba config:

I have changed to database pgtest and grant privileges.
    postgres=# \c pgtest;
    You are now connected to database "pgtest" as user "postgres".
    pgtest=# grant all privileges on all tables in schema public,jiaofayuan to pguser;
    GRANT;

The permission info:
pgtest=# SELECT grantee, privilege_type FROM information_schema.table_privileges WHERE grantee = 'pguser' AND table_schema = 'jiaofayuan';
 grantee | privilege_type
---------+----------------
 pguser  | INSERT
 pguser  | SELECT
 pguser  | UPDATE
 pguser  | DELETE
 pguser  | TRUNCATE
 pguser  | REFERENCES
 pguser  | TRIGGER
(7 rows)

pgtest=# SELECT grantee, privilege_type FROM information_schema.table_privileges WHERE grantee = 'pguser' AND table_schema = 'public';
 grantee | privilege_type
---------+----------------
 pguser  | INSERT
 pguser  | SELECT
 pguser  | UPDATE
 pguser  | DELETE
 pguser  | TRUNCATE
 pguser  | REFERENCES
 pguser  | TRIGGER
 pguser  | INSERT
 pguser  | SELECT
 pguser  | UPDATE
 pguser  | DELETE
 pguser  | TRUNCATE
 pguser  | REFERENCES
 pguser  | TRIGGER
(14 rows)


Have you granted usage of the schema?

The public schema by default is, well, public

Note that as the question stands, you forgot to connect to the new database before creating the schema.
